# RedisDesktopManager not connecting to remote redis server

Tags: redis

I had a perfectly running remote redis-server on my LAN (@ x.x.x.x:p). I was able to use the RedisDesktopManager to view the server contents. However, there were a lot of dangling connections to my server from different clients (subscribed to channels) which I wanted to close so I used the `SHUTDOWN` command from the console of the desktop manager. Since them, I am unable to connect to the remote server. The desktop manager is running and lets me add a new redis-server connection but I am not able to connect to the previous server connection. Whenever I try to connect to the server @ x.x.x.x:p, the desktop manager terminates.  I have not made any configuration changes to the previously running server so I am sure that I am not making any mistake with port bindings. Any help on what I am missing will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you connect to your remote server using telnet or redis-cli? Is the remote Redis server up at all? (BTW, don't give your server's IP and port here... that's just inviting trouble)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you performed a shutdown, and since then you can't connect to Redis? Did you relaunch the server?

Comment: I tried relaunching the server but it is not starting up.

Comment: If it is not starting up it is a different issue than not able to connect. What error do you get when you try to start it?

Comment: The remote server is running on a VM so I use port forwarding to remotely connect to the server. I am using a redis remote desktop client to connect to the server. When I enter some random server IP, I get a "Can't connect to redis-server" error. But, when I try to connect to the remote redis-server, the desktop client is force closed without displaying any error.

Comment: Problem solved: The server was running but the bindings were not correct. I had 3 bindings in the configuration file; I changed it to only 1 binding and everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the configuration binding. The bind line in the configuration file was originally
`bind 132.168.131.129 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0`. I changed it to `bind x.x.131.129`. The server connection was restored.